# Different IdentityServer instances running in the same subdomain

Tags: identityserver4

Let's say that I need to have multiple and different instances of IdentityServer running in the same subdomain, example:

```
https://dev.mycompany.com/identityserverversion1
https://dev.mycompany.com/app1version1
https://dev.mycompany.com/app2version1

https://dev.mycompany.com/identityserverversion2
https://dev.mycompany.com/app1version2
https://dev.mycompany.com/app2version2

https://dev.mycompany.com/identityserverversion3
https://dev.mycompany.com/app1version3
https://dev.mycompany.com/app2version3
```

I have no problem with SSO, when I login in **identityserverversion1** I am also authenticated in **app1version1** and **app1version2**. If I close the browser and do the same test in **identityserverversion2** and **identityserverversion3** both "environments" are also working. The problem comes when I am logged in in **identityserverversion1** and now I try to login in **identityserverversion2**, I am not even able to view the login page.

Should this be possible with IdentityServer? or only 1 independent instance  per subdomain is allowed?

Answer (score 0):

You can't share multiple instances on the same domain, because they all will share the same cookies out of the box.

To run multiple instances on the same domain, you need to use different ports for each instance.